# How to add a second where clause to a linq expression

Tags: linq, iqueryable

Trying to add a second where clause to a linq expression but it won't register.

```
var query = _dbSetBookedResource.AsQueryable<Resource>();

var resources = (from Resource in query where Resource.DateFrom == date select Resource)


if(true)
{
resources.Where(b => b.MemberId == currentUserId);
}
```

For some reason the second where clause won't register.

Comment: Aren't you looking for something like `where Resource.DateFrom == date && Resource.MemberId == currentUserId` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason the second where clause won't register.

That's because you're not using the return value anywhere. That's just setting up a query, but then ignoring it. No LINQ methods *change* the value they're called on - instead they create a *new* query which has the appropriate filtering, projection etc.

You need:

```
resources = resources.Where(b => b.MemberId == currentUserId);
```

Also note that your initial query could be written more simply as:

```
var resources = query.Where(r => r.DateFrom == date);
```

Query expressions are overkill when all you want is a simple filter or projection.